# Marriage visa refusals and conditions

Tags: customs-and-immigration

If I'm refused a marriage visa will it affect me from going back in the country on a visitors visa?

Comment: You need to add more details. Which country you are applying for, what your citizenship is, what your fiance's citizenship is, and preferably what the refusal notice said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's the point of a visitor visa? In general, the country you want to visit does not want you to become an illegal resident so they run a through background check on your ties, finances and so on. There are other concerns of course (security, mostly) but this is the most important one.

Once you indicated you want to get married in a given country your credibility of "hey I am just visiting" drops to near zero since you already explicitly stated you actually wanted to marry and settle. In general again you won't find explicit laws or regulations saying you can't get one but you will face an almost insurmountable credibility challenge.

Comment: Thanks for your answer sir it's just a heart breaking situation after going through all the documents and going the right path and still failing I'm from barbados and my fiance is British we've been together 3 years now and wanted to tie the knot but we're left hanging not sure of my reàson yet as I only got an email stating my marriage visa denied have to wait on my package to see the letter